# Как узнать из скольки знаков состоит число?

Tags: c++

Есть число, например 31, нужно узнать сколько знаков в числе (двухзначное трехзначное и т,д)
Как это сделать?

Comment: делить на 10, пока не обнулится. Устраивает? :)

Comment: Через  степень 10 - `std::ceil(std::log10(n)) + 1`

Comment: [man sтprintf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf) (только не забудьте проверить его знак)

Comment: Самый простой способ, это перевести число в стринг и взять длину стринга ;)

Comment: Сравнивать со степенями 10, как станет меньше, столько знаков.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>

int len(int n) {
    int res = 0;
    if(n <= 0) { ++res; }
    while(n != 0) { ++res; n /= 10; }
    return res;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << len(-534) << '\n';
    std::cout << len(0) << '\n';
    std::cout << len(534) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```